# How to replace every space within a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

```
x = input("")
print(str(x), sep="...")
```

First off this is Python 3.
These are the lines of code I have created.
I am looking to replace each space with ...
When I input `Hi I am Mike`, the output is `Hi I am Mike`.
I thought that the "sep" part would make the separation `...` instead of a space.

So basically I am receiving the exact same input as output and I thought that I would receive `Hi...I...am...Mike`.

I tried looking on the python source code and on here but it seems everyone is so far above my level that I just cannot find the simplicity I am in need of.
What I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work as `sep` requires several parameters in `print` to have an effect.

You have many ways.

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and unpacking:

```
s = 'Hi I am Mike'
print(*s.split(), sep="...")
```

`split` and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
s = 'Hi I am Mike'
print('...'.join(s.split()))
```

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
s = 'Hi I am Mike'
print(s.replace(' ', '...'))
```

Output: `Hi...I...am...Mike`

Answer (score 1):

The `sep` only works if you provide multiple strings. Like this:

```
strings = ["Hi", "I", "am", "Mike"]
print(strings[0],strings[1],strings[2],strings[3], sep="...")
```

So first `split` your input on spaces, then combine those with the `sep` parameter.

```
my_input = input()
my_input.split()
```

Comment: split() won’t help you apply `sep` to user input of unknown size, though.

Comment: you are right, in such case `replace` is probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace() method:

```
string = "Hi I am Mike"
new_string = string.replace(" ", "...")
print(new_string)
```

And the output is:

```
Hi...I...am...Mike
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use replace if you're looking for simplicity.

The first line declares your input.
Always be sure to set your new value, which I'm doing on the second line.
The final line prints out the new value, with the replacement done.
Worked for me on Python 3.

`x = 'Hi I am Mike';`

`newValue = x.replace(" ", "...");`

`print(newValue);`